# Get parameters of an Attribute using Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

My question is there any way to retrieve the parameter list with its value using Reflection?

I want to use reflection to get the parameter list from the PropertyInfo.

```
 Author author = (Author)attribute;
 string name = author.name;
```

is not OK. As there will be many Attribute, which is not typeof Author.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property,  AllowMultiple = true)]
public class Author : Attribute
{
    public Author(string name, int v)
    {
        this.name = name;
        version = v;
    }

    public double version;
    public string name;
}

public class TestClass
{
    [Author("Bill Gates", 2)]
    public TextBox TestPropertyTextBox { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

using this program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine("Reflecting TestClass");
            foreach (var property in typeof(TestClass).GetProperties()) {
                foreach (Author author in property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Author), true).Cast<Author>()) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tProperty {0} Has Author Attribute Version:{1}", property.Name, author.version);
                }
            }
            var temp = new TestClass();
            Console.WriteLine("Reflecting instance of Test class ");
            foreach (var property in temp.GetType().GetProperties()) {
                foreach (Author author in property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Author), true).Cast<Author>()) {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tProperty {0} Has Author Attribute Version:{1}", property.Name, author.version);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class Author : Attribute {
        public Author(string name, int v) {
            this.name = name;
            version = v;
        }

        public double version;
        string name;
    }

    public class TestClass {
        [Author("Bill Gates", 2)]
        public TextBox TestPropertyTextBox { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I get this output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume by parameter list, you mean a list of all attribute uses?

If not, this code shows you how to get an attribute using reflection on a whole class. But you should be able to take what you need.

So here is a method to find all attributes of a certain type, on any property inside a `TestClass`

```
public IEnumberable<Result> GetAttributesFromClass(TestClass t)
{

    foreach(var property in t.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        foreach(Author author in property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Arthor), true))
        {
             // now you have an author, do what you please
             var version = author.version;
             var authorName = author.name;

             // You also have the property name
             var name = property.Name;

             // So with this information you can make a custom class Result, 
             // which could contain any information from author, 
             // or even the attribute itself
             yield return new Result(name,....);
        }

    }
}
```

Then you could go:

```
var testClass = new TestClass();

var results = GetAttributesFromClass(testClass);
```

Also, you may want your `public double version` and `string name` to be properties.
Something like this:

```
public double version
{
    get; 
    private set;
}
```

Which will allow `version` to be set from the constructor, and read from anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. My case is that do not use the static class. So using Author author = (Author)attribute; is not OK.  I want to use reflection to get the parameter list from the PropertyInfo.

Comment: Can you define parameter list?

Comment: Parameter list is that I can get ("Bill Gates", 2) dynamically using reflection with have to use "Author" to cast attribute.  Because there will be many such Attribute, some may not be Author attribute.

Comment: Well then you could iterate over the attribute and get all the properties?

Answer (score 0):

```
string name = author.name;
```

is not allowed because the field `name` is not public.  Does it work if you make `name` public?

Comment: Sorry it's a typo, I added the public back.

Comment: Your latest edit reveals your problem.  Either use `GetCustomAttributes` with a type parameter to filter and only look at attributes which are `Author`, or else use `Author author = attribute as Author;` instead of a cast, to do a dynamic type check, and ignore the ones that come back `null`.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue in one of my apps. this is my solution:

```
public static string GetAttributesData(MemberInfo member)
{            
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // retrives details from all attributes of member
    var attr = member.GetCustomAttributesData();
    foreach (var a in attr)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("Attribute Name        : {0}", a)
            .AppendLine();
        sb.AppendFormat("Constructor arguments : {0}", string.Join(",  ", a.ConstructorArguments))
            .AppendLine();
        if (a.NamedArguments != null && a.NamedArguments.Count > 0 )
        sb.AppendFormat("Named arguments       : {0}", string.Join(",  ", a.NamedArguments))
            .AppendLine();
        sb.AppendLine();
    }            
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

i have tested your example.

```
var t = typeof (TestClass);
var prop = t.GetProperty("TestPropertyTextBox", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var scan = Generator.GetAttributesData(prop);
```

here is output:

```
Attribute Name        : [Author("Bill Gates", (Int32)2)]
Constructor arguments : "Bill Gates",  (Int32)2
```